# Table extraction with Scrapy failing

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to extract links in a table from a [Website](https://ecocyc.org/gene?orgid=ECOLI&id=G7688#tab=GO) (classname internal), but I always get Crawled 0 pages, but downloader get a bunch of bytes.

```
class geneDetails(scrapy.Spider):
name = "details"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = ['https://ecocyc.org/gene?orgid=ECOLI&id=G7688']
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):


    details = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"internal")]/tbody/tr').extract()

    for det in details:
        gene_det =  det.xpath('./text()').extract()
```

Already tried a lot of things, but never worked, the code above was my last try, sorry for anything, not a specialist on scrapy/xpath.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't open the specific part for "GO"

```
https://ecocyc.org/gene?orgid=ECOLI&id=G7688#tab=GO
```

To get this data you need to load

```
https://ecocyc.org/gene-tab?id=G7688&orgid=ECOLI&tab=GO
```

You can find the urlpart in

```
tabIds[tabIds.length] = 'GO';Y.one('#GO').setData('uri', '/gene-tab?id=G7688&orgid=ECOLI&tab=GO');
Y.one('#GO').setData('clim-reqd-p', 'true');
```

Parsing the result table would be the next step.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand what urlpart in the code means, why only the https://ecocyc.org/gene-tab?id=G7688&orgid=ECOLI&tab=GO, do not work?

Comment: The page is structured in different parts from which some are loaded through javascript when you click at some buttons. Your Spider code does open the corresponding links to load this detaildata.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, but even using https://ecocyc.org/gene-tab?id=G7688&orgid=ECOLI&tab=GO, it do not work..

Comment: Your xpath was not correct as well response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"internal")]').extract() gives a result but the result of your xpath is empty ... you have to debug this with scrapy shell